# Trying to connect to sql server 2012 from within Excel using ADODB connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have some code written in VBA. I need to query a table in a sql server 2012. I cannot get the connection to work. Below is what I have tried so far without any luck.

The error message I get is "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done."

```
 Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
 Dim cnString As String

 cnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
                    "Server=MyServerName;" & _
                    "Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;" & _
                    "Integrated Security=False;"

 cn.Open cnString, "myID", "myPassowrd"
```

Comment: Try this:  `cnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=YourPassword;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=YourLogin;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Data Source=YourSqlServer."`  Then open the connection.

Comment: Also try `"Driver={SQL Server};Server=SERVER\INSTANCE; Database=MYDB; UID=sa; PWD=password"` and then `cn.Open cnString`